# how to set up firebase realtime database eventListener in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I am trying to add an event listener to my react native app that triggers on changed however it does not trigger until I refresh the application. I think I am setting up the event listener incorrectly but I do not know how else to do it.

Here is my code:

```
render(){

    Firebase.database()
    .ref('/UserToQuestion/' + Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .orderByChild("Question")
    .on('value', snapshot => {

         console.log('-----------');



        var i = 0
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {



            var childData = childSnapshot.val();



            titlesArray.push(childData.Title)
            contentArray.push(childData.Question)
            dataArray.push({title:titlesArray[i],content:contentArray[i]})
            i++
            console.log( titlesArray);



   });

 })
```

Putting it outside the render method gives an error of the currentUser.uid being undefined, but I think that the listener only being triggered on render is the problem so how would I have it always being triggered?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it up so you create the firebase reference when the component is being constructed. I think something like this should work. I've added comments to explain what I've done:

```
class MySuperAwesomeClass extends React.Component {
  // this will be a fixed reference you can use to attach/detach the listener
  firebaseRef;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // assign a reference to this component's firebaseRef member
    this.firebaseRef = Firebase.database().ref(
      `/UserToQuestion/${Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`
    );

    // grab the data from the server and call this.onFirebaseValueChanged every time it changes
    this.firebaseRef.orderByChild("Question").on("value", this.onFirebaseValueChanged);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // detach all listeners to this reference when component unmounts (very important!)
    this.firebaseRef.off();
  }

  onFirebaseValueChanged = snapshot => {
    console.log("-----------");
    // I created these arrays because they didn't seem to exist
    const titlesArray = [];
    const contentArray = [];
    const dataArray = [];

    // use let instead of var because it's changing
    let i = 0;
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      // use const instead of var
      const childData = childSnapshot.val();

      titlesArray.push(childData.Title);
      contentArray.push(childData.Question);
      dataArray.push({title: titlesArray[i], content: contentArray[i]});
      i++;
      console.log(titlesArray);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Render method shouldn't be talking to the server!</Text>;
  }
}
```